# Allure Specflow 3.5.0.4 throwing exception System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void BoDi.ObjectContainer.RegisterTypeAs(System.String)"

Tags: specflow, allure

I need help to resolve exception that I am getting during allure specflow setup.

I have implemented Allure Specflow with Specflow 2.4.1 and it has worked perfectly.

I have updated Specflow and Specflow MSTTest to 3.7.13 and AllureSpecflow 3.5.0.4 however after upgrade I am getting below error

> Assembly Initialization method SNOW_MSTestAssemblyHooks.AssemblyInitialize threw exception. System.MissingMethodException: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void BoDi.ObjectContainer.RegisterTypeAs(System.String)'.. Aborting test execution.

I am not sure why I am getting this error, If I remove Allure Specflow then my tests are working fine.

Any help here is really appreciated.

Comment: Does Allure require the BoDi Nuget package? If so, which version does it use? Can you [edit] your question to include enough code for a [repro]?

Comment: @Greg,  I am not sure if Allure requires BoDi, this is 1st time I am facing this issue. I will create example soon and upload in a git

Comment: @Greg https://github.com/javed0211/CRM_Automation.git use this link to see the code

Answer (score 1):

The SpecFlow Allure plugin doesn't support any SpecFlow versions after 3.5. It is not yet updated to use the latest versions.

The only workaround I have in mind is that you stick with SpecFlow 3.5 until Allure is updated.

Comment: I tired using Specflow 3.5.5 and Specflow Allure 3.5.0.4, I am not getting above error however I am getting  error - Value can not be null  )

Comment: When I debug test cases in Visual studio I get System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key'
as soon as test case start executing

Comment: I have added code here https://github.com/javed0211/CRM_Automation.git

Comment: The exception is thrown within Allure. No idea why. I would create an issue in the GitHub repository. https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-csharp

Comment: I have created an issue, however for now issues is resolved by downgrading Specflow to 3.1.97 and allure to 3.0..0.10, I will wait until issues is fixed by allure to upgrade specflow

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved by downgrading Specflow to 3.1.97 and allure to 3.0.10. I am able to run test cases and allure reports are generated.